# increment and decrement date in angular 8 in dd-MM-yyyy format on button click

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to increment and decrement date on button click and set value to input box this is the code

```js
    prev() {
         let diff = 1; //1 to increment and -1 to decrement
         this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - diff);
         console.log(this.date);
    }
    next() {
         let diff = 1; // 1 to increment and -1 to decrement
         this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + diff);
         console.log(this.date);
    }
```

In html file

```html
       <input type='text' id='datepicker' name='datepicker' class="form-control" 
       [ngModel]="{{date | dd-MM-yyyy}}">
        <button (click)="prev()"></button>
        <button (click)="next()"></button>
```

Comment: Is this not working? The only thing I see wrong is the comment in `prev`; since you're using `- diff` it should 1 to decrement and -1 to increment... All you need is buttons that call `prev` and `next`.

Comment: i have added button but still not working  but  in console.log  date displays i am not able to set in input field

Comment: You're using one-way binding; `[ngModel]=` rather than [two-way binding; `[(ngModel)]=`](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel)

Answer (score 0):

you could do you like this (24h=86400000ms)

```
 prev() {
    this.date = new Date(+this.date - 1 *86400000);
 }

 next() {
    this.date = new Date(+this.date + 1 *86400000);
 }
```

Comment: The current code works fine, as long as `this.date` is set to a `Date` object.